# Shortcode not showing $content in correct place

Tags: shortcode

I asked this elsewhere but I'm not getting very far with the answers, so thought I'd try here as it's specific to Wordpress. I have this shortcode:

```
function reytab($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('title' => '#'), $atts));
    return '<div class="tab">'.
        '<h2 class="reytab">'.
            $title.
        '</h2>'.
        '<div class="tab-content">'.
            do_shortcode($content).
        '</div>'.
    '</div><!-- End div.tab -->';
}
add_shortcode('reytab', 'reytab');
```

And I'm calling it in my wysiwyg editor in Wordpress like this:

[image: Shortcode in wysiwyg editor]

This is the markup that's generated from my shortcode and as you can see the `$content` is being rendered outside of the `.tab-content div`:

```
<div class="tab">
    <h2 class="reytab">Title</h2>
    <div class="tab-content"></div>
</div>
...content appears here...[\reytab]
```

You can see that `[/reytab]` is being rendered as part of the `$content`, so I'm assuming my issue is something to do with either the shortcode, a conflict with a plugin (which it's not as I've deactivated all of them to test that) or a conflict in my theme (which I'm also assuming it's not as I tried this with TwentyEleven - although, as I'm using a child theme that relies on TwentyEleven, it's still possible it's a conflict I guess).

Can anyone offer some advice on what I can try? I'm really lost as to what I can check.

Thanks

Osu

Comment: What happens if you change `[\reytab]` to `[/reytab]`? I think your slash is just backwards and things are trying to compensate for the mismatched elements caused by that.

Comment: @m0r7if3r You are amazing. I can't believe it was that simple, I feel like such a d**k. Please provide this as your answer and I'll credit you with solving my problem.

Comment: Hah, we all have those days. Solution submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, the issue is in your shortcode. If you look around line 200 of `/wp-includes/shortcodes.php`, you can see that only `/` is supported for the close tag, not `\`. If you change `[\reytab]` to `[/reytab]` it will work!